# didDeselectRowAt gets called after two taps

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

After the first tap the row gets highlighted (gray background), and then I've to tap any of the following rows to perform the segue.

I do get the right readings, for instance `indexPath.row` returns 0 if I tapped the first row initially to begin with and then it doesn't matter which row I tap next to make it work.

It's a subclass of `UITableViewController`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // delegate?.onSelect(users![indexPath.row])
    print("selected %d", indexPath.row)
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToUserForm", sender: users![indexPath.row])
}
```

I did erase all content and settings from the hardware menu of the simulator.

Comment: don't you want to implement `didSelectRowAt`?

Comment: sorry I did't get the question, I do want to implement, not sure what am i missing here.

Comment: didDeselectRowAt != didSelectRowAt

Comment: oh yes, smh, lol :) thanks man, this solved, wasted lot of time on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using `didDeselectRowAt`. This means that this code is called not after the tableCell is selected on the first tap, but when it is deselected on the second tap. Therefore, your code should not be this:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // delegate?.onSelect(users![indexPath.row])
        print("selected %d", indexPath.row)
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToUserForm", sender: users![indexPath.row])
    }
```

But this:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // delegate?.onSelect(users![indexPath.row])
        print("selected %d", indexPath.row)
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToUserForm", sender: users![indexPath.row])
    }
```

Of course, `didDeselectRowAt` is useful in specific situations, however, it seems that it is not useful in your case. In short, replace `didDeselctRowAt` to `didSelectRowAt`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `didSelectRowAt` not `didDeselectRowAt` to perform the segue.
`didDeselectRowAt` is triggering in second tap because the 1st tap triggers `didSelectRowAt`.

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       //Your Code
    }
```